# Spring + Thymeleaf resource handler conflicting with RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

After registering an "generic" `@RequestMapping` my resource handler stopped working.

At first I has this resource config, with Thymeleaf:

```
@Value("${ty-resource}")    
private String resource;

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(resource);
}
```

My resources are outside the project, so then my client may update it's resources on his will(he asked for it).

Everything was ok, my resources was beeing delivered from `${user.dir}/../webapp/resources/`

Then I registered the `@RequestMapping(value="/{department}/{category}/{subCategory}")`.

Then my resources started to be responded by this request mapping instead from the resource handler.

I don't know what to do for resolving this issue.

I thought about this:

```
@Value("${ty-resource}")
private String resourcesPath;

@RequestMapping('/resources')
public ModelAndView resources(@RequestParam("r") String resource) {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+resourcesPath+resource);
}
```

But I don't think this may be the best answer.

Even trying this, as the `@RequestMapping(value="/{department}/{category}/{subCategory}")` is registered before than `@RequestMapping('/resources')`, my resource get responded by the `@RequestMapping(value="/{department}/{category}/{subCategory}")`.

-- Edit --

Example:

`<script type="text/javascript" data-th-src="@{/resources/js/components.js}"></script>`

This resource request is responded not by the resource handler.
The spring get it as a matching for the `@RequestMapping(value="/{department}/{category}/{subCategory}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by implementing the `Ordered` interface in my Controllers.

So I setted a greater order to the controllers which I wanted to be resolved as the last ones.

Answer (score 0):

Ths is how i am loading resources using Thymeleaf

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
  }
```

and using the absolute path in html to load resources as

```
<script th:src="@{/resources/js/validation.js}"></script>
```

Do look at [How to harness url in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110964/how-to-harness-url-in-spring-mvc) selected answer.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I completed the question.